# chart primefaces zero line

Tags: java, primefaces, charts

I create bar chart in java primefaces.

The chart has negative and positive values.

I want to add origin line which seperates negative and positive values at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it directly via any attributes you add to the `<p:chart>` tag nor the model in your backing bean.

However, the chart renders as an HTML5 [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), which allows you to draw on it with javascript.  I managed to draw all over the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml)  through Chrome's dev tools by adding an id attribute to the canvas, then typing this into the console:

```
var c = document.getElementById("newCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,217);
ctx.lineTo(1276,217);
ctx.stroke();
```

With yours, you will have to figure out what the correct values of the X and Y coordinates are, and these may change as your model values change.  I expect you are going to need to calculate this somehow.